# Looping through an array in react and adding them to a select option

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]i need help in this problem im facing... so im trying to loop through an array of countries and put it into my select form but the problem im having is i get an error when i try to select in item in the drop down.. here is the code.

```
// an array of country names
const countryNames = getNames();
// example output
["united states", "united kingdom", "syria", "spain", "mexico"]
//state
const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
function handleCountry({target}){
setCountry(target.value)
}

//the form
<select name="country" value={country} onChange={handleCountry}>
{countryNames.map((country) => {
  return <option value={country}>{country}</option>
})}
</select>
```

when i click on the form on the browser i can see the names in the dropdown but if i select a country i get an error... i know its probably a dumb question but i kinda need help with this lol.
BASICALLY my question is how do i pass the selected option into my onChange function..
Thanks!

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

i have found an answer, basically, i was using a ui component library "antd", and their select component had an "onSelect" prop which you could pass the value from that into your onchange

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function handleCountry(country, index){
  setCountry(target.value)
}

<select name="country" value={country} onChange={handleCountry}>
  {countryNames.map((country, i) => {
    return <option key={i} value={country} onSelect={() => handleCountry(country,i)}>{country}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: yeah this is exactly what i found out, thanks for the help!!